# Solving the recurrence relation $T(n) = (T(\sqrt{n}))^2$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I am stuck on this one recurrence relation, trying to find the asymptotic upper bound, and I have done it in two ways with two different answers, but I think they are both wrong.

Recurrence: $T(n) = (T(\sqrt{n}))^2$

Firstly, I tried guessing $O(n^2)$, therefore:
$T(n) = (\sqrt{n^2})^2 = n^2$ which is $\in O(n^2)$
So $T(n) = O(n^2)$ ?

Then I tried another way, assuming $n = 2^k$ for some k. Then,
$T(2^k) = (T(2^{k/2}))^2 = T(2^k)$ (Can you do that? I don't think so?)
If so, then since $n = 2^k$ that means $k = log(n)$, so finally:
$T(n) = 2^{log(n)}$ ?

Any advice on how I could go about this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: notice that $2^{\log(n)}\sim n$. In fact, if you try $T(n) = n$, it still works. It means that to get the solution you should reason differently...

Comment: Where you start matters. If you want pattern spotting then you might assume $T(2)=k$ , then looking at $T(4)=T(2^2)$ and $T(16)=T(4^2)$ and so on , then spotting a pattern.  I would have thought the result is something like $T(n)=n^c$ for some $c$: your $2^{\log_2(n)} =n$ is an example of this when $c=1$.  Your earlier $n^2$ is another example when $c=2$.

Comment: As we have $T(k^{2^m})=T(k)^m$, then we can write $T(n) = T(n^{\frac{1}{2^m}})^m$. As $n^{\frac{1}{2^m}}\to 1, m\to\infty$, and $m=\log_k \log_2 n$, then I obtain rough estimation  $T(n)=O(T(1)^{\log \log n})$.

Comment: @zkutch Notice that $T(k^{2^m}) = T(k)^{2^m}$ is the right one

Comment: Thanks  @Exodd. Corrected variant: From $T(k^{2^m})=T(k)^{2^m}$  we have $T(n)=T(n^{\frac{1}{2^m}})^{2^m}=T(n^{\frac{1}{2^m}})^{\log_k n}$. So,  $T(n)=O(T(1)^{\log n})$